# Is there any way by which I can convert escape chars to backslash in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, path

My string has some escape characters in it, I want to replace those chars with backslash followed by char. For example :-

var a = "\n" here it is rendered as newline character
I want it to be "\n"

I have a path variable  = "F:\test\abc.txt"

here path is rendered with escape characters. I want it to retain backslashes.

Comment: You can escape backslashes just the same as all other characters: put a backslash in front of it: `\\n`

Comment: I cannot do that ,I am receiving the string with escape characters. is there any way i can change it after I receive it?

Comment: Yes, with a regex replace, eg. for all newlines and tabs in a string you would do: `var explicitEscapes = textStrWithNewlinesAndTabs.replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/\t/g, '\\t');`

Comment: But there can be any char followed by "\" not just "\n" and "\t". What would be the regex in that case

Answer (score 0):

Try a double `\\`. one for acknowledging the escape character and the other one to retain the backslash

Comment: I am receiving the string with escape chars, there seems to be no way I can replace it with double slashes and retain the escaped character.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a "\" before your escape character.
like this:

```
var str = `\\n`;
console.log(str);// logs \n
```

if you are receiving data and you want to change it then try replacing the \n to \\n by using replace method.
like this:

```
var str = "\n hello world\n";
//use regex to replace it
function changeString(str) {
   return str.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
}
console.log(changeString(str));
```

Comment: It works to replace \n but since it is a path string it can have any alphabet [a-z]. What will be the regex in that case. I have tried `/\\[a-z]/g` But it is not working.

Comment: i used `/\\[a-z]/g` in regex testing websites but it seems it doesn't work in code.